# Installation of openzeppelin/contracts Library

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I have created a node.js project, within which I have created a truffle directory and initialised its project. I have installed the openzeppelin (npm install @openzeppelin/contracts) library in this truffle project directory, but nothing appears to have been installed, although I did not received any error during the install process. The import statement in my project displays the error hereafter:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
```

> Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Thank you. J

Answer (score 3):

If you run `npm uninstall @openzeppelin/contracts` and then `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts@2.3.0`, then retry the import, then it should work.

Also, check your truffle-config.js file and see if the root directory is configured properly to find your `node_modules` folder properly.

Comment: Thank you Max for your comment. I have run the 2 commands above in order to install the proper version of openzeppelin. However, I am not finding any example on how to configure the truffle-config.js file so that the node_modules folder can be properly found.

Comment: Add this to your contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "insert path to your contracts folder here"),
```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "./contracts"),
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: 'yoursolcversionhere'
    }
  }, networks:{
    ....
};```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time Max. Actually, it appears that my project hadn't been initialised properly for some reason. After running npm init again, everything is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `ERC721Full.sol` no longer exists, as you can see in the [Github repository](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC721). From the [latest update](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/releases/tag/v3.0.0) (`v3.0`) of the OpenZeppelin contracts, you can read the following:

> `ERC20` and `ERC721` were simplified and streamlined, including all
> optional parts of the standard by default, and simplifying some of our
> own custom extensions.
>
> [...]
>
> If you're using the `ERC20` or `ERC721` tokens however, you'll have to
> remove all references to optional extensions (`ERC20Detailed`,
> `ERC721Enumerable`, etc.) - these have been included in the base
> contracts.

You should use `ERC721.sol`, which includes the parts of `ERC721Full.sol`:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
```

If you want to install a specific version (example: [`v2.3.0`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/releases/tag/v2.3.0)):

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts@2.3.0
```

Comment: Thank you Alberto for your comment. However, the file does exists at the following URL, and it is working properly in Remix. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC721 I believe that there is a problem with my install.

Comment: @JF0001 Yes, but this is the version `v2.3` of the contracts. I supposed that you wanted to use the latest version because you didn't use a specific version in your npm command.

Comment: Thank you again Alberto. Understood, but even if I specify the URL that you have provided, I am still obtaining the same issue. I definitely believe that there is a problem with my install. However, I am not able to find any command online that I can use to see the version of openzeppelin installed.

Comment: You can check your `package.json` file, for example: `$ cat package.json`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time Alberto. Actually, it appears that my project hadn't been initialised properly for some reason. After running npm init again, everything is working properly.